# I fell for the sugar daddy scam

Tags: scams, legal, sugar-daddy

So, long of the short. They offered to pay off my meager credit card debt. I was able to cancel all the payments but one. I called my bank and reported a fraudulent payment. It was for $211.

So, am I going to jail or will the charge reverse and I pay my bills like usual?

I know I made a mistake, please don't rub it in.

Comment: "I was able to cancel all the payments but one.  I called my bank and reported a fraudulent payment."  Thumbs up!  "am I going to jail"  For this?  Doubtful, but law.SE is the better place to ask.  "and I pay my bills like usual?"  You'd still owe the money even while still in jail... :)

Comment: @RonJohn thanks for the laugh, I sort of feel better. I'll crosspost over there. Thank you.

Comment: @mistakemaker It is not clear from the question what actually happened. Did someone charge your credit card and you canceled those charges? Did someone send you money you didn't ask for and reversed those transfers? Did you forward funds you received to other accounts and reversed the transfers you made?

Comment: To really answer the going to jail question, we'd at least need to know what country (and state, in the US) you live in, since laws differ.

Answer (score 5):

You can only go to jail for doing something illegal, and then it typically has to be not your first offense, and you have to be unwilling to cooperate with authorities to catch "the bigger fish".  Falling for a scam is not a crime.  I would put your chances of going to jail, at zero, with the information you provided.

It is a bit unclear, from your post, who was harmed.  What information did you give away, the credit card details?  If so that card should be canceled right away.  I would work with the credit card's fraud department and ask them for advice on what can be done.  You may want to close this account all together and either get a credit card with a different company.

There are some really positive take away's from your question.  First you realized that this was a scam pretty early.  Second you are trying to make things right.  [Here is a story of an older man that should know better that lost his life saving to a similar scam.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2-JNjUT7caU)   You didn't do that!

So build on this.  Go forth and do great things.  Know that the fastest way to become wealthy is to do so slowly.  Get out of debt, invest, and do things to increase your income.